# How do I avoid a delay when sending email from my application?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a small console application. It checks a few settings, makes some decisions, and sends an email. The problem is the email doesn't actually get sent until my application finishes. I want the email sent as soon as my method that sends the email completes.

Initially, I just created a MailMessage and called `.Send()`. That's when I noticed the mail was not being sent until the app finished.

Then I tried using the task parallel library.

```
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => msg.Send());
```

Again, the messages don't get sent until my entire application finishes.

How do I sent an email when `msg.send` executes, not when the app completes?

Comment: How certain are you that it is not getting sent until the app closes?  Send() is a synchronous method.  It could be there is a delay at the Smtp server.

Comment: @Kevin - I wait after stepping through the method that does the sending. SMTPClient.Send() has already executed and I'm into another method. I wait for 15+ minutes and nothing appears in my inbox. As soon as I hit F5, the messages appear within a second or two of the app completing. If I don't wait (just let the app run w/o breakpoints), the messages appear within a second or two.

Comment: Is your SMTP server local to your machine or is it on another machine?

Comment: @Kevin - The SMTP server is on our LAN, not local.

Comment: I find this scenario bizarre.  All I can offer to you is to try running Fiddler and see when the packet of data is being sent to the SMTP server. It should be sent as soon as .Send() completes but you can double check, it might give you more information.

Comment: @Kevin - I agree this is bizarre. I tested this at home and the message arrived in my inbox before the application completed  its Thread.Sleep(300000). This is as expected and what everyone was telling me. It's still a mystery why this doesn't work on our corporate network.

Answer (score 3):

`SmptClient` supports async sending of mail via `SendAsync`, however in practice in a web application this hangs the request thread.

To avoid blocking I recommend using the `ThreadPool` to fire off the email in a background thread. This won't block your application.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(...))
    {
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(...))
        {
            client.Send(mailMessage, Tuple.Create(client, mailMessage));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what the state of Async operations in ASP.NET were in 2011, but `SendAsync` should not hang the request thread now (ASP.NET 4.5+). That's the whole point of async/await - to return the thread to the thread pool until the async call completes.

Answer (score 0):

The most sure fire way to avoid delays would probably be to use a pickup directory, which will queue the message rather than send it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new MailMessage and send it with SmtpClient.  It will send immediately.  I will add an example.

EDIT: Populate the variables host, port with the smtp ser ver name and port number.

```
using (var mailer = new SmtpClient(host, port))
{
    using (var message = new MailMessage(sender, recipient, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = false })
    {
        mailer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        mailer.EnableSsl = useSSL;
        mailer.Timeout = Timeout;
        mailer.Send(message);

    }
}
```

If you still experience a delay, then the delay will be at the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a SMTP client. do it like this:

```
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            //fill in your message
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(FromAddress, FromPassword);
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(SmtpHost, SmtpPort);
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Credentials = nc;
            sc.Send(mm);
```

at this stage your mail will be sent.

But, sending an email is an async act, so it will take some time until you recive the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Simply dispose the MailMessage and SmtpClient objects after the .Send() function.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("server", 25);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

MailMessage message = new MailMessage("ToAddress","FromAddress");
message.Subject = "Test email";
message.Body = "Test email";

smtpClient.Send(message);

message.Dispose();
smtpClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: how does this help with the delay ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SmtpClient with setting:

```
smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 2;
```

https://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/tip-14-solve-smtpclient-issues-of-delayed-email-and-high-cpu-usage