# High responsetime from Web API after 5 min inactivity

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-web-api

I have a weird problem in a preproduction environment.

I have a website which performs some operations on a Web Api hosted on another server.

Usually it takes under a second to make a specific post request, but after 5 minutes of inactivity the same post request will take 10-30 seconds. (According to google chrome network tab)

The mentioned post request is not the first request in a list of requests performed.

The request is done using Ajax.

I have run SQL profiler to see if the database queries were running slow, but these are all performing fine, and it looks like the POST request is just returning with a delay.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to response time? The request should send rather quickly. Most likely it is an issue with your web API, possible authentication/caching related. It's hard to say without any knowledge of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The problem was that an email was sent using SMTPClient in the request.

In a web application the smtp client is not async and therefore it had to be sent before the POST request returned.

Making it async using the reply from TheCodeKing in this question: 
    [How do I avoid a delay when sending email from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339396/how-do-i-avoid-a-delay-when-sending-email-from-my-application)

solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

A very likely cause is compiling at the database level.  The first time you run a query with most database engines, the sql has to be compiled and an execution plan developed.  This is then cached for a while.  When it is no longer cached, it has to be done again.  The longer your sql string, the longer it takes to compile.

The solution is to use a stored procedure.  Once it runs once it stays compiled and the execution plan is always available.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan. However when I look at the profiler it looks like all the database queries are run, and then nothing happens in 10-30 seconds.