# Very high responsetime after 3 min inactivity Web API

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a weird problem in a preproduction and production environment (but not in dev).

I have a website which performs some operations on a Web Api hosted in the same IIS.

Usually it takes under a second to make a specific POST request, but after 3 minutes of inactivity the same POST request will take 10-30 seconds. (According to google chrome network tab)

The mentioned POST request is not the first request in a list of requests performed.

The request is done using Ajax.

I ran SQL profiler to see if the database queries were running slow, but these are all performing fine, and it looks like the POST request is just returning with a delay. All the SQL queries are performed straight away, and when they are done nothing happens for the mentioned 10-30 seconds.

Do you guys have any idea why the responsetime is so high?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem was that an email was sent using SMTPClient in the request.

In a web application the smtp client is not async and therefore it had to be sent before the POST request returned.

Making it async using the reply from TheCodeKing in this question:
  [How do I avoid a delay when sending email from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339396/how-do-i-avoid-a-delay-when-sending-email-from-my-application)

solved the problem!